# Changing colors of atoms and bonds imported from PDB files

Tags: import, color, color-management

I am attempting to model some small molecules in blender. I have successfully imported the structure of these molecules, and while I can move, rotate, and change the size of the molecules without issue, I have found that attempting to color the components (atoms, bonds) of these molecules has not worked using the node editor. I created a cube in blender and proceeded to change its color without issue, so I think the node editor itself is fine. If anyone could help instruct me on how to change the colors of the imported pdb object, I would be very grateful.

Comment: please add screnshots or upload the file somewhere :) 
Do your models have individual materials?

Comment: Make sure the render engine is not workbench and that "use nodes" is checked!